# Передача данных между Activity

Tags: передача-данных, android, android-intent

Здравствуйте, начал писать приложение под Android и у меня возник вопрос, как передать данные с одного Activity сразу на **два**?
Опишу свою задачу точнее, у меня есть первая активити `MainActivity`, по нажатию на кнопку открывается другая активити `VremActivity` с наследством от `tabActivity`

Вот код:

```
public class VremActivity extends TabActivity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vrem);

        // получаем TabHost
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // инициализация была выполнена в getTabHost
        // метод setup вызывать не нужно

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 1");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, OneActivity.class) );
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 2");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
}
```

Эта активити отображает во вкладках две активити `OneActivity и TwoActivity`
Так вот, с активити `MainActiviry` нужно передать данные в `OneActivity и TwoActivity`.
За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Определите что-нибудь типа евента в классе приложения, подпишитесь в MainActivity на него, а в OneActivity и TwoActivity вызывайте этот евент. Приложение доступно во всех активити через getApplication();

т.е. например:

Определяете классы:

```
class MyEvent {
    public void fire(String someParam)
    {
    }
}

class MyEventListener {
    private ArrayList<MyEvent> _events = new ArrayList<MyEvent>();
    public void addEvent(MyEvent event)
    {
        _events.add(event);
    }

    public void fireEvents(String param){
        for(MyEvent event: _events)
        {
            event(param);
        }
    }
}
```

В классе приложения (Если Вы его не создали, то Вам его надо создать)

...

```
  private MyEventListener _eventListener = new MyEventListener();
  public MyEventListener getEventListener(){ return _eventListener; }
```

...

В главном активити перед вызовом (один раз) вешаете обработчик евента например так:

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).getEventListener().addEvent( 
    new MyEvent(){ 
        public void fire(String param){ 
            if(param=="data1"){
            }else if(param=="data2"){
            } 
        }
    });
```

...

В своих активити для передачи данных пишите:
...

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).getEventListener().fireEvents(myParams);
```

...

Comment: Извините, а не могли бы вы по-подробнее, а то  изучать Android начал совсем недавно и не понял, как это реализовать, с таким ещё не сталкивался.

Comment: Ну, андроид тут особо не причём. Что именно Вам не понятно?

Comment: Ну Вы сказали определить в классе приложения евент, я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Аналогично делаете наоборот, т.е. во втором и третьем активити добавляете свой евент, а в главном активити вызываете fireEvents(...)